# How can stop to show the time value in reportviewer

Tags: c#, mysql, report

The date field have a error in Microsoft reportviewer. I want only show the date value not time. I only store date value in my database.But the time value show every time . I use this connection string to store and view data.

```
MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=drgnit_school;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Allow Zero Datetime=True");
```

Please help me how can i avoid to show the time value in my report.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can update only day value in date value in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764852/how-can-update-only-day-value-in-date-value-in-mysql)

Comment: The linked answer, which this was a duplicate of, is removed now..